# Recursive series MIPS isn't working as expected

Tags: recursion, assembly, mips

I must implement a recursive series in MIPS, here is the high level code:

```
int suite(n)
{
if (n == 0) return 0;
else
return (suite(n-1) + 4*n);
}
```

I have several problems with my assembly code. The first one is that it doesn't give the expected result, as it adds 4 each time.

My second problem is that it doesn't end. I've used a recursive textbook example for a factorial. 
Here's the assembly code:

```
.data 
msg: .asciiz "Entrer un nombre : "
.text
.globl  main

main:
#print msg
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,msg
    syscall
    #input prompt
    li $v0,5
    syscall
    addi, $a0, $v0, 0
    jal suite

suite: 
    addi $sp, $sp,-12
    sw $a1, 8($sp)
    sw $a0, 4($sp)
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $t0, $0, 1
    slt $t0, $a0, $t0
    beq $t0,$0 else
    addi $sp, $sp, 12
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    add $v0, $0, $0 
    jr $ra  
else:   
    add $a1, $a0, $a0
    add $a1, $a1, $a1
    addi $a0, $a0, -1
    jal suite 
    lw $ra, 0($sp) 
    lw $a0, 4($sp)
    lw $a1, 8($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 12
    add $a0, $v0, $a1
print:  
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    add $v0, $0, $0
    jr $ra
end:
```

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: What happens when the `jal suite` in `main:` returns?

Comment: At some point, it goes back and forth between main and suite. I was able to tweak the code so it works, but I added some beq and some global variables to make it end.

Comment: My point was that you need to exit the program after `suite` returns to main, instead of just falling through to the `suite` code.